# Why does phosphine have a dipole moment and a higher boiling point than carbon tetrafluoride?

Tags: boiling-point, polarity, dipole, vsepr-theory

Phosphine, PH<sub>3</sub>, and carbon tetrafluoride, CF<sub>4</sub>, are small molecules of a similar size and the same mass of 88 au. CF<sub>4</sub> has a dipole moment of 0, which is unsurprising given its tetrahedral shape. However, I would expect P-H bonds to be non-polar (P and H have electronegativities of 2.19 and 2.2) and therefore the molecule to also have a dipole moment of about 0, despite being trigonal pyramidal and therefore asymmetrical. So I would expect it to exhibit similar intermolecular forces and a similar boiling point to CF<sub>4</sub>. Yet PH<sub>3</sub>'s dipole moment is quoted as 0.58 D. And PH<sub>3</sub> has a boiling point of -88 °C and CF<sub>4</sub>'s is -128 °C.

Why does phosphine have such a higher dipole moment and boiling point than CF<sub>4</sub> despite it having non-polar bonds?

Comment: Mass of phosphine is nowhere near 88. Not that it matters much, though.

Comment: Damn it, I confused myself because it has a boiling point of -88C. It's PF3 that has a mass of 88 as well.

So actually my question should be: why does phosphine have a higher boiling point than phosphorus trifluoride?

Answer (score 2):

The dipole moment of $PH_3$ can be attributed to the lone pair on P, which is directed away from all three P-H bonds. You can imagine that there is a higher electron density near the lone pair, while the electron density is more or less uniform near the nonpolar P-H bonds. This does not happen for $CF_4$, so it has no dipole moment.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I screwed up my question completely. I meant to ask: why does PH3 have a higher b.p. than PF3 when it is less massive and has virtually non-polar bonds, whereas PF3 has polar bonds and is asymmetrical? They both have the same shape.